# Isolate two column features under conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze the World university rankings from Kaggle.com.

[How the data look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWc7W.png)

My problem is that i want to isolate from the data the universities from the column `country==France` and from `year==2014`.

here is the code I have so far:

```
FR <- cwur[cwur$country=="France", cwur$year=="2014",]

  output$p6=renderPlot({p6 <- ggplot(FR[1:25,],aes(country, national_rank , label = institution )) +
    geom_point() + geom_label_repel(aes(fill=factor(country)), colour="Yellow", fontface="bold")+
    xlab("Countries") + ylab("national rank") +
    labs(title="France's top 25 Universities with cwur")
  print(p6)
  })
```

I tried to extract the year using `cbind` and other functions but with no result.

How do I isolate the column year and under the condition that is 2014 ?

Comment: FR <- cwur[(cwur$country=="France" & cwur$year=="2014"),]

Comment: Comma is delimiting arguments. In a data.frame, first element is rows and second columns.

Comment: Thanks @EdwardMoseley! I tried '&&' but I did not consider only one ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the comma to an '&' (`cwur$country == 'France' & cwur$year == '2014'`), you should be able to do selection based on both year and country.

Comment: Thanks you very much !!